# Different output in read text files that have same text in C++

Tags: c++, text

I wrote a code which read a text file and print to stdout by adding '-' chracter to end of the line. And I tested two different name files that have same text but result is different. I don't understand. Please someone explain.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream file (argv[1]);
    string line;
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (file,line) )
        {
            cout << line.c_str() << '-' << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I run this command with it:

```
./a.out test.txt
```

Output is:

```
Some text written-
More input to this file-
Data01323526-
AnotherData09142-
```

Then I run this command with it:

```
./a.out pr.txt
```

Output of last command is:

```
-ome text written
-ore input to this file
-ata01323526
AnotherData09142-
```

"pr.txt" and "test.txt" have same text. You can download them for testing there: 
http://www.megafileupload.com/anP3/pr.txt

http://www.megafileupload.com/anP4/test.txt

These have same text which has 71 characters.

```
Some text written
More input to this file
Data01323526
AnotherData09142
```

Why does different the output? And how can I read that output always will be same?

Comment: It's OT, but why do you use `line.c_str` instead of `line`?

Comment: I usually use such way, does it change the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.txt` is a file with unix encoding of 71 bytes.  Under this encoding, the newline is encoded as as 1 char:  `0x0A` (aka `'\n'`).

`pr.txt` is a file with dos/windows encoding of 74 bytes.  It has the same textual content, but newlines are encoded as 2 chars: `0x0D 0x0A` (aka `'\r'` and `'\n'`).

If you execute your programme under linux on `test.txt` everything is fine.

If you execute it on `pr.txt`,  the `0x0A` is considered to be the end of each line, so, you'll add the '-' just before this position.  The programme works as designed, but the `0x0D` and `0x0A` are separated by the dash.

But when you now display the result for `pr.txt` under linux, when the `0x0D` is printed (it means "carriage return" for consoles), the cursor gets placed at the begin of the line, and the '-' overwrites the first char ON THE SCREEN.  So the content of the file is correct: only the display is weird.

***Additional remark:*** if you would have executed the same programme on `pr.txt` under windows,  you would have got the correct result.  This is due to the default text-mode when you open files.  The text-mode on windows will read the two char line separator `0x0D 0x0A` as if they were a single `'\n'`. you would then place '-' before it, and when writing back to disk, the standard library would uncompress the `'\n'` into the platform specific `0x0D 0x0A`.  Even if displaying the result under linux, you'd see the correct result, because '-' is printed at the end of line, then the '\r' will cause no visible effect as it is followed ly '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Carriage return and line return are separate characters. Are you sure you have the same line endings in both files? Perhaps try to edit with vim and use set: list

Comment: I use copy-paste to copy text file from pr.txt to test.txt.